How to configure UserRoles when using Microsoft Identity and extending the IdentityUser and IdentityRole model? Creating duplicate tables
I'm using EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.6 and Microsoft.Identity.Core 8.0.6.
I have a extended the models for user and roles
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
    ...
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User>? Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}

and
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Role>? Roles { get; set; } = new List<Role>();
}

This is my db context:
public class ApiDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    public override DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public override DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options) : base(options) {   }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

This is creating numerous problems for me. Not only does it create the AspNetUserRoles table it's creating a duplicate table called RoleUsers. And because of this when I query the db to get a user with roles the roles are always empty:
    User? user = await _context.Users
        .Include(u => u.Roles)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == request.Id);

I would simply like to get a user with a list of their list of Role objects populated, but I'm struggling to get Entity Framework to work with Microsoft Identity.
I've tried various combinations in the db context to map the table but IdentityUserRole doesn't know what a Role or User is so having trouble mapping it.
Update:
I've no longer got duplicate tables. But for some reason EF Core will just not let me access UserRoles. No matter what I do it will not retrieve any user roles. This is going normal. It's a pretty simple query to get data from a joined table so Im not sure what is going on.
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } = new List<UserRole>();
}

and the same in the roles model.
My db context:
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(b =>
    {
        b.HasMany<UserRole>(u => u.UserRoles)
            .WithOne(ur => ur.User)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
            .IsRequired();
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(b =>
    {
        b.HasMany<UserRole>(r => r.UserRoles)
            .WithOne(ur => ur.Role)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
            .IsRequired();
    });

Query that returns no roles for some reason:
User? user = await _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
        .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == request.Id);

I'm at my wits end trying to get EF Core to let me query my tables.

what authority provider are you using? I use Active Directory and simply created an Azure function that intercepts my signin user flow. There I add the roles and claims prior to the ticket being added to the cookie. You shouldn't need to extend or change the Identity models.

I'm not using one. I would just like to be able to get a list of role objects with my user.
